# Is there a simple generic implementation of rule based access control?

Tags: web-applications, architecture, access-control

I'm implementing the access control of an intranet site. Which would be easy, if the company didn't have 200+ employees and custom permissions for almost every one. It's madness, I know, but I can't change it.

So, I tried to find a generic implementation which would meet my needs, but couldn't find it, so I went to do it myself. In the end, I came up with a fairly generic solution which got me thinking: someone must have done it before!

I called it STOP (Subject Task Object Permission) Access Control. I have the following relation:

```
.-------.     .-----------.     .-------.
| users |1---*| STOPRules |*---1| tasks |
`-------'     '-----------'     '-------'
```

A STOP Rule has the following attributes

```
STOPRule {
    Subject;
    Task;
    ObjectType;
    Permission;
    Relation;
}
```

The object relation can be: owner, creator, revisor, etc. This field isn't required, to support generic tasks. When it's there, the relation between the current user and the object instance is calculated by a delegate. The current relation is then compared with the required relation on the rule to allow or deny the access.

Let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Two questions arise:

1. Is there an open source implementation like this one?
2. Do you see any problems I would encounter following this path?

**EDIT:** I went ahead and actually started to implement this model. The first problem was I needed the relation between the subject and the object to support any use case. Now, I can store the following rule:

**John** (subject) **can** (permission) **edit** (task) an **order** (object) IF he is the **creator** (relation) of the order.

Please, can you guys provide a REALISTIC use case that couldn't be expressed using this model?

Comment: +1 for the "office space" type atmosphere - you probably all fill out tps reports too.

Comment: As an aside for your model design, does [Role Based Access Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Role-based_access_control) sound like it fits the bill model-wise? Your title was so close to this I wondered if that's what you meant originally.

Comment: @Ninefingers no, unfortunately it's not. rOle-based AC and rUle-based AC share the same acronym but are different and I meant the second one. On rule-based ac, the rules for access are defined in the object (or resource) to be secured (speaking from a operational system view) adapting it to Web, the closest I've seen is the Zend_Acl an ACL implementation on the Zend framework, but it expects me to load all the permissions, since it's rOle and not rUle based, it assumes that it will be a lot less permission rules.

Comment: Let's try a use case: Allow John to view a special message between 5 and 6 pm if he provides a special password.

Comment: @koen, it isn't really a realistic use case, is it? That's why I added 'simple' to the question. I don't expect this model to cover ALL use cases, but the majority of the realistic ones.

Comment: @koen Anyway, I'm using a combined approach which uses two Auth providers, one based on the model above and another one using the specification pattern to define access rules. So, even in this case, I'm covered.

Comment: I'm stymied by your use of the word "realistic." I wouldn't think any organization would try to do permissions for 200 people without categorizing them (e.g. with roles). I guess realism is relative.

Comment: @Justin, I agree with you, personally I think it's insane what they are doing. Actually, there are roles, but I've been asked too many times to allow only Jane Doe to edit some field, so I'm trying to create something that will have my back.

Answer (score 1):

What about actually having one table with grouped permissions by certain roles and use another table for extended permissions that would override general ones. If it is the case of let only John access something, why also mention that each other person cannot? Like for the last example you provided in the comment above: do there is a table with permissions. A record looks like: 1645 edit_some_field. Then group_permissions looks like: `1645 everyone false` and the final exception table would be `1645 (Jane Doe's ID) true`.

If, let's say there are 50 people who have access to edit this field, then you just add another group in the group table like: `89 editors_of_field_X`, put the people's IDs into a table `group_members` like `89 (John Smith's ID) true`. And then on the final step you can override those with single person's permissions as I mentioned above. So in conclusion you would have 3-layer scheme. Everyone-group-person. And the deeper you go the higher importance that role has. For example if everyone is not allowed, but the group you are in is allowed, then you can edit something.

Moreover if you aren't permitted with an access on the third - person - level, then again, you became an exception in the group. This way you will be able to reuse groups for later, only adding minor changes.

Comment: What happens if one person is a member of two groups, and one is allowed to edit and the other isn't?

Comment: Good point. But it is left for decision of the author of the question: either not allowed, or allowed or checking the latest one.

Comment: Hey, @AndriusNaruševičius, thanks for the taking the time to answer with so much detail. As projects have deadline (It has passed 20 days since I asked), so I went ahead and implemented the model I describe. Well, kinda. I made some improvements. E.g. doesn't make sense to define a user when you define the relation to the object. I'll write something about what I came up with and post here later. As to your answer, I'll comment on that later, but you basically described how the rOle based access control works.

Answer (score 1):

John created an order and wants to let Bob view it.

Comment: You save somewhere that bob was invited to view that order (so the system is able to evaluate the "invited" relation at runtime, as it does for any relation) and add the STOPRules (user,task,object_type,permission,relation) the values (null, "view", "order", "allow", "invited").

I came to the conclusion that setting the user is only useful for exceptions. Good example, though!